# Go from tutorial_category to tutorial. Do I need to use a join or include?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a tutorials model that looks like this:

```
class Tutorial < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :title
  has_many :tutorial_categories
end
```

and a tutorial_category model that looks like this:

```
class TutorialCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :tutorial_id
  belongs_to :tutorial
end
```

When I know the tutorial_category via something like `@tutorial_category = TutorialCategory.find(params[:id])`

How can I get all the tutorials that belong to that tutorial category. Put another way, once I know @tutorial_category.name, I want all tutorials that have the same tutorial_category.name set.

Do I need to use a join or include to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you're using the wrong type of relationship here. You're trying to model a `many to many` relationship with a `many to one` setup. I'd setup your models like the following. This assumes you have a join table called `categories_tutorials` with the fields `category_id` and `tutorial_id`. Also note I changed the name of your categories model as it was very close to the conventional Rails join table syntax.

```
class Tutorial < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :title
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tutorials
end
```

To find all the Tutorials for a given category you can now do something like the following:

```
a = Category.find(:params[:id])
tutorials = a.tutorials
```

Comment: That makes sense. Maybe I was trying to get too creative and avoid the join table.